# Python - função Type em tuplos

Tags: python, tuple

Olá,
Estou a tentar fazer um programa em Python, que recebe um número inteiro positivo.

Esse programa deverá verificar se é inteiro (**com a função type**) e se é **positivo**. Deverá devolver um **tuplo** de inteiros contendo os dígitos desse número(inteiro), pela ordem em que aparecem no número.

Por exemplo:

```
>>> Insira um numero inteiro positivo: -31 
>>> Insira um numero inteiro positivo: olá 
>>> Insira um numero inteiro positivo: 34501 
(3, 4, 5, 0, 1)
```

Alguma ideia, por favor?

obrigado,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pra verificar se é inteiro, podemos comparar o resultado da função `type` com `int`:

```
>>> type(10) == int
True
```

Pra verificar se é positivo, devemos ver se o número dado é maior do que 0:

```
>>> -2 > 0
False
>>> 3 > 0
True
```

Transformar o número em uma tupla com suas partes pode ser feito mais facilmente transformando o número em uma string, a dividindo e depois transformando de volta em int:

```
lista_digitos = []
for digito in str(34501):
    lista_digitos.append(int(digito))
tupla_digitos = tuple(lista_digitos)
```

Ou, de um jeito mais conciso com uma expressão geradora:

```
>>> tupla_digitos = tuple(int(digito) for digito in str(34501))
>>> tupla_digitos
(3, 4, 5, 0, 1)
```

Juntando tudo e combinando com `input` do usuário:

```
while True:

    n = input('Insira um numero inteiro positivo: ')

    # Tentamos transformar n em inteiro (entrada original é string).
    # Se não conseguirmos, recomeçamos o loop perguntando novamente.
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        continue

    # Aqui não precisamos mais comparar type com int
    # porque temos certeza de que o programa só chegará
    # nesse ponto se n for int. 
    # Se compararmos type(n) com o n original (logo depois 
    # do input), o resultado nunca será True, já que input
    # retorna uma string.

    if n > 0:
        print(tuple(int(digito) for digito in str(n)))
```

Resultado:

```
Insira um numero inteiro positivo: 123
(1, 2, 3)
Insira um numero inteiro positivo: -123
Insira um numero inteiro positivo: Não número
Insira um numero inteiro positivo: 123485
(1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 5)
```

Comment: Está muito bem elaborado! Muito obrigado!